# Equivalent of apt-get on OpenELEC

Tags: linux, operating-system, raspberry-pi, package, apt-get

I'm currently working on a raspberry pi, which has OpenELEC as operating system. Unfortunately, apt-get can't be used on this distribution. I have a lot of things to install, and it would be way too long to do it without apt-get.

So my question is : Do you know any equivalent command of apt-get that can be used on OpenELEC, or a way to use apt-get on this OS?

Eventually, which OS would you advice me so I don't encounter this problem anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternatively you could compile your desired software from source using an arm compiler and use `scp` to transfer the whole installation to your pi. `wget` could also help if binaries are available online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OpenELEC WIKI:

> Unlike other XBMC distributions, OpenELEC isn't based on Ubuntu,
>   Debian or Arch - in fact, it's not based on any distribution. Instead,
>   OpenELEC has been built from scratch specifically to act as a media
>   center. This means it can be streamlined to certain hardware and only
>   needs to include the packages absolutely required, making OpenELEC as
>   streamlined as possible. In addition, OpenELEC is designed to be
>   managed as an appliance - it can automatically update itself, is
>   managed almost entirely from within XBMC and boots in seconds. You
>   never need to see a management console or have Linux knowledge to use
>   it.

So the answer is: you can not use apt-get or similar.

You can change OS and use the official OS Raspbian, or if you need a media center you can use [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/)